# Firefox scrolls down on page load

Tags: javascript, firefox, scroll

When I visit my site in firefox, the homepage never gets loaded scrolled to top. It randomly scrolls down a certain amount of pixels (which seems random, sometimes even halfway down).

I turned javascript off, no help. Could reproduce it on Windows/Mac, real machines + browserstack.

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I can give a link to the live site, http://realo.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, just an autofocusing attribute that was set, pretty stupid